# header is getting merged with content in my pdf itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

This is my code my header gets overlapped with the content when added the page event:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("E:/testing.pdf", FileMode.Create));

writer.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
doc.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello world. Checking Header Footer");
    para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

    doc.Add(para);
    doc.NewPage();
}

doc.Close();

class HeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PdfPTable tbHeader = new PdfPTable(4);
        tbHeader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width -document.LeftMargin- document.RightMargin;
        tbHeader.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

        tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph());

        PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("working"));
        _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        _cell.Border = 0;

        tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);
        tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph("working fine"));

        _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        _cell.Border = 0;
        tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);
        tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph("working good"));

        _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        _cell.Border = 0;
        tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0,-1,document.LeftMargin,writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin), writer.DirectContent);
    }
}
```

Added the page event - I'm using iText version 5

I also want to add line break after header

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your code in the correct order.

It sounds like you may be adding your header to the main body.

```cs
// Must have write permissions to the path folder
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\demo.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
Paragraph header = new paragraph("HEADER")
   .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
   .SetFontSize(20);
 
document.Add(header);
document.Close();
```

The full usage document is here:

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/generating-a-pdf-document-using-c-.net-and-itext-7.html

**EDIT:**

I see the original document above has been edited to mention that you are using iText version 5. In Visual Studio, there is no option to install that version, so my code example shows iText version 7.

I also see that you implemented your own **HeaderFooter** class based on the **PdfPageEventHelper** so that you could override the **OnEndPage** event. It looks like you are trying to create some type of Wait Cursor in the document while it is being created, but you can't really do that because you are writing to a document. Everything you successfully write there is going to be a part of your document.

Comment: The OP's code is for itext 5 (or earlier) while your code is for itext 7.

Comment: @mkl - the document has been edited. That information was not there when I posted my answer. Should I delete this or leave it for others? The OP might not even know that this is a free plugin.

Comment: You could simply mention the fact in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly tell itext to add the header table in the main page content area:

```c#
tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0,-1,document.LeftMargin,writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin), writer.DirectContent);
```

You might want to replace

```
writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin)
```

by

```
writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin-20)
```

or something like that to remain above.